# Interchangeable Parts in OrCAD CIS

Tags: orcad

We just started using OrCAD Capture CIS at the company I work for, and we were wondering how can 'treat' interchangeable parts.

When we migrated our current library we found that we had several caps of the same value and parameters from different MFRs.

Some of them are a bit more expansive, and some are obsolete, is there a way to hide them from the CIS search and just keep the one we want to use from now on, or do we just have to delete them from the catalog?

This is basically a 'best-practice' question regarding OrCAD CIS, any help and advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I worked at a company for a year that used the software, and they had obsolete components from 10 years+ ago in the database - numerous occasions I accidentally put obsolete components in my schematics. This was a massive company, and if they did not bother I presume you have to manually delete them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That sounds just like the big company I've worked for before :)